# FuzzyWuzzy in python for matching thousands of rows

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I have an excel worksheet with 4 columns as SPI1, D, SPI2, O and they are sorted by SellerPartyId ie SPI. I would like to see those in O which are not present in D. The number of rows on Originator Name is over 20,000 while those in DBAName is around 1,000. I have seen a number of solutions but it does not match my desired results. I am quite new to Python so any help would be awesome.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xZ8O.png)

Comment: Please post your code.  It is hard to follow what you are saying and to even understand your problem.

Comment: I have just been able to import fuzzy libraries and import the sheet, I want help with how the code would look like if we want to match the string in a row with thousands of rows in different column and find whether or not there is a match or how similar are 2 strings and which of the string is totally different.

Comment: def fuzzy_match(x, choices, scorer, cutoff):
    return process.extractOne( x, choices = choices, scorer = scorer, score_cutoff = cutoff)
FuzzyWuzzyResults = Data.loc[:, DBAName].apply(fuzzy_match, args= (Data.loc[:, OriginatorName], fuzz.token_set_ratio, 50))

Comment: This is what I am trying to do wherein Data is the name of excel sheet and I am trying to match OriginatorName against the DBAName with a similarity ratio of 50

Comment: @AniketPadwal please include your code *in your question*. It is impossible to comprehend it in the comments.